# Faster display shut off

Tags: hdmi, display

When I tried to use `tvservice - o` to turn off my screen which worked but when I used `tvservice -p` to turn back on it didn't work. Is there any way to change the time it takes to turn off the screen? The display is hdmi.

Answer (score 1):

You can go into your screensaver settings and change the time it kicks in.
[Link](http://www.theraspberrypiblog.com/blog/screensaver-power-saving-on-raspberry-pi)

Although it you might be able to bring it back with a commandline of :

```
xset dpms force on
```

Comment: `xset -display :0 dpms force off` does set on the screensaver but does not turn the screen off...